# Celery worker setup and teardown

Tags: celery

My Celery tasks require resources that are a bit expensive to setup but can be reused for many tasks on the same thread, but need to be closed when the worker shutdown. (Specifically, they require a fake X display using Xvfb used to render).

I can easily use a `threading.local()` variable and only initialize the resource once per thread, but the shutdown process is not so clear. The questions I have are:

- Does Celery restart threads in the pool ever? If so, the resource needs to be restarted as well (or at least migrated)
- Is there a way to detect when an entire worker is going down and shutdown the processes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [signals](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/signals.html) for almost everything in Celery, so in your case, it sounds like you're looking for [worker-process-shutdown](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-shutdown) signal.

I guess you can do something like (pseudo code):

```py
@worker_process_shutdown.connect
def shutdown(*args, **kwargs):
    # release your resources here..
    pass
```

Comment: @coderforlife does it answer your question? :)

Comment: The decorator seems to be `@worker_process_shutdown.connect`. Other useful ones seem to be `worker_shutting_down` and `worker_shutdown` and likewise, there are startup ones that may be useful as well.